# Vectorized String Concatenation numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

So i am need of a fast way to join rows of an array if they are strings and filtering out empty and None values. The first approach was to the data as a pandas dataframe where I would populate the array with a result column and then update the array in place with df.update where i would apply the operation with df.apply(), but as we know df.apply() gets quite slow when operating on a huge dataframe.

Next approach was to just handle it with numpy, the issue is we need to filter out empty string values and values that are not strings, as we only want to concatenate the columns that actually are strings.  And we want to join with a delimiter.
So let's have a look at a couple of examples of what i am trying to achieve

A plain one with delimiter as ' - ' is

```
| A   | B   | C   | D   |
|-----+-----+-----+-----|
| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
| 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' |
```

Turns into

```
| A   | B   | C   | D   | Result          |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------------|
| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'a - b - c - d' |
| 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'e - f - g - h' |
```

Another example with None's and non strings same delimiter

```
| A    | B   | C   | D    |
|------+-----+-----+------|
| None | 'b' | 1   | 'd'  |
| 'e'  | 'f' | 'g' | None |
```

Turns into

```
| A    | B   | C   | D    | Result      |
|------+-----+-----+------+-------------|
| None | 'b' | 1   | 'd'  | 'b - d'     |
| 'e'  | 'f' | 'g' | None | 'e - f - g' |
```

I've created some numpy with masking that does exactly this, but still seems be slowish

```py
nan_mask = np.where(np.logical_or(operate_v == '', operate_v == ' ', operate_v == None), True, False)
operate_v[nan_mask] == ''
de = np.full((operate_v.shape[0], operate_v.shape[1] - 1), delimiter).astype('object')
V = np.zeros((operate_v.shape[1] + de.shape[1] , operate_v.shape[0])).astype('object')
de[nan_mask[:, :-1]] = ''
de[nan_mask[:, -1]] = ''
V[0::2] = operate_v.T
V[1::2] = de.T
done = np.sum(V, axis = 0)
df[:, target_idx] = done
```

So basically I am creating a mask where the empty / None values are, and then creating a delimiter array and updating that according to the nan_mask and interweaving the two arrays such that we can sum it and then update the original dataframe. Hope the approach makes sense. There is also an implementation that only uses normal python lists, which outperforms the numpy approach by far, let's take a look.

```py
empty = {
  None: True,
  ' ': True,
  '': True,
}

result = list(
  map(delimiter.join, map(
    lambda values: filter(
      lambda v: not empty.get(v), values
    ), zip(*data))))
```

Since each row is not dependent on the last, we should be able to speed this up by vectorization, but I don't seem to manage. I Hope it makes sense what I am trying to do, any help in trying to speed it up?

Comment: 'vectorization' usually means using compiled numpy methods on the whole array.  You've done that, but your array is object dtype, not numeric.  numpy doesn't do much of its own string handling; it use python string methods.

Comment: Since you're dealing with strings the list comprehension approach is most likely the fastest possible.